# onclick function need to execute a simple javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button where I am trying to add on click jquery as below

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">YES</button>
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function myFunction(){
        $('#mycheckboxdiv').toggle();
        $("div#headersteptwo").addClass("hidden");        
    }
})
```

However, on click I am getting **Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined**

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

Updated with a sample jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3aC7W/1/

Comment: You havent included jQuery in your fiddle.

Comment: You cannot access the function inside another function globally. you have to make your inner function globally like `window.myFunction = function () { alert('It works now'); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

You are defining the function inside another function, i.e. the function is **not** defined in global scope and hence cannot be found by the inline event handler.

Just remove `$(document).ready(function() {` because you don't need it there:

```
function myFunction(){
    $('#mycheckboxdiv').toggle();
    $("div#headersteptwo").addClass("hidden");        
}
```

You only have to use `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` if you manipulate the DOM, and also only if you place the script before the elements in the HTML document.

---

The better solution of course would be to bind the event handler with jQuery (and not use inline event handlers):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        $('#mycheckboxdiv').toggle();
        $("div#headersteptwo").addClass("hidden");        
    });
});
```

You might have to add a class or ID to the button to make the selector more specific. Have a look at the [list of available selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Note that in your fiddle, the JavaScript code is already placed inside a ready event handler. You also have to change the option from `onLoad` to `no wrap`.

Answer (score 1):

change your code to this way to achieve click :

```
<button id="myFunction">YES</button>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myFunction').click(function(e){
        $('#mycheckboxdiv').toggle();
        $("div#headersteptwo").addClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

check it at: http://jsfiddle.net/aneesh_rr/XJ758/3/

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.myFunction = function(){  //you should make myFunction avaliable in global
        $('#mycheckboxdiv').toggle();
        $("div#headersteptwo").addClass("hidden");        
    }
})
```